# Hive table joining : I have a partitioned table and wanted to join with another table

Tags: hive

Partitioned table (table1):
[image]

second table (table2):
[image]

Needed output (table3):
[image]

With Single query it didnt work, so I tried with multiple queries. I had issue with only one partition. So I separated the query based on same.

For the issue less partitions :

```
insert into table3 partition(paritioned_c4) select a.c1,a.c2,a.c3,a.partitioned_c4 from db1.table1 a where partitioned_c4<>’3’;
```

For the rest part :

```
insert into table3 partition(paritioned_c4) select a.c1,a.c2,a.c3,a.partitioned_c4 from db1.table1 a join table2 b on a.c1=b.t1;
```

Comment: can you use `UNION ALL` or `UNION`?

Answer (score 1):

you need to join both tables. Create a subquery and then join both tables on a key.